# Fallos de la validación de registro en PHP

Tags: php, html

muy buenos dias, Estoy aprendiendo a crear usuarios para paginas web con PHP. A la hora de ver el video, a el profesor le funciona todo bien, y yo siguiendo tal cual sus pasos me marca todos estos errores:

[image: fallos]

Realmente no se donde esta el error, El registro del usuario lo tengo hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php
//Registrar usuario
if (isset($_POST["registrar"]))
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['pass']);
$password_encriptada = sha1($password);
$sqluser = "SELECT idusuarios FROM user WHERE user = '$user' ";
$resultadouser = $connect->query($sqluser);
$filas = $resultadouser->num_rows;

if ($filas > 0) {
    echo "<script>
    alert('El usuario ya existe')
    window.location = 'index.php'
    </script>";
}else{
    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(Username,Email,Password)
    VALUES ('$username', '$correo','$password','$password_encriptada')";
    $resultadouser = $conexion->query($sqlusuario);
    if ($resultadouser > 0){
        echo "<script>
        alert('Registro Exitoso')
        window.location = 'index.php'
        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Error')
        window.location = 'index.php'
        </script>";

    }
}
?>
```

Y el HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <br>
    <br>

<div class="loginbox">
    <p>User</p>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="user">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="passwoard" id="passR" name="passR">
    <button name="registrar" class="button" href=index.php>Continue</button>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Realmente soy muy nuevo en esto y quisiera poder solucionar estos problemas, Todo tipo de fallos y consejos son muy bien recibidos. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: En tu código veo una variable `$connect` pero no veo donde la declaras

Comment: Hola BetaM, Gracias, no habia puesto el include para llamar a el file, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: como dijo @BetaM no tienes declarada la variable `$connect` o  bien la tienes en un archivo externo y en ese caso una posible solución podría ser agregar el nombre del archivo  donde tienes declarada la variable mediante la sentencia `include` luego de la apertura de la etiqueta `<?php` . Quedaría asi `<?php //Registrar usuario  include("nombredearchivo.php"); if (isset($_POST["registrar"]))` . Para mas informacion referida a esta sentencia [https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes empezar siguiendo los errores de la consola de PHP,

"Undefined variable: connect", esto es pista de que estas usando una variable no declarada, en tu codigo esto parece que es lo que abre/instancia el link a tu DB, puede ser mysqli o el que estes usando.

"Undefined index: email", puede ser de lo anterior, si tratas de usar una variable no declarada en ninguna parte para hacer tu conexion, y esperas utilizar un resultado de un campo "email", entonces el resultado que tienes es nulo y no puedes acceder a un indice declarado como "email".

mysqli_real_escape_string() error: viene igual de lo anterior, pasas una variable no declarada para abrir la conexion, que es el primer parametro que espera la funcion, entonces te declara como un boolean del tipo false, y la funcion falla.

Comment: Augusto, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, poco a poco voy logrando solucionar problemas, el que estoy teniendo ahora es que no puedo entender algo. No se supone que al poner $email ya la estoy declarando? Porque los problemas "undefined index" no los estoy pudiendo solucionar. Muchas gracias

Comment: Sera por el table.sql? Me salieron muchas fallas, abrire un nuevo post

Comment: Generalmente, al hacer una consulta a una base de datos, el resultado es asignado a una variable de tipo array, cuando haces fetch por ejemplo en PHP a la consulta de MySQL, una llamada comun es darle nombre $result o $resultado, entonces a ese array para acceder a un campo utilizar el nombre del indice, si usaste fetch associative, poder usar el nombre del campo que tienes en el BD, por ejemplo $resultado["email"]

Comment: Amigo si tienes un servidor, sube el contenido, estas en localhost, y algunas veces con los proyectos en htdocs lanzan esos errores de php, suele pasarme, pero al subirlos al servidor de pruebas funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Mire otra vez tu codigo, y ese error de indexado de email es porque $_POST no estaria recibiendo el email, chequea tu formulario